# How to setup a cron job in cake php? And which file to use to create the script?

Tags: cron, cakephp-2.0

How can i set a cron job in cake PHP and which file to use to create the script?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **cakephp 2.x**. 
Under app/Console/Command/ create a php file like FilenameShell.php .

In **FilenameShell.php** include the following code

class FilenameShell extends AppShell {

```
//Instead of main you can write your own function name 
 public function main(){
      //your code goes here ...
       $this->out('Hello world.');
     }
}
```

The conventions for shell classes are that the class name should match the file name, with the suffix of Shell. In our shell we created a main() method. This method is called when a shell is called with no additional commands. We’ll add some more commands in a bit, but for now let’s just run our shell. From your application directory, run:

Console/cake functionname

**Note : -** If your function name is main no need to mention it . if Its other than main just plae you function name and enter .you can see the result once you enter the command .

You should see the following output:

### Welcome to CakePHP v2.0.0 Console

App : app

### Path: /cake_dev/app/

Hello world.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very easily by the following steps -:

1) Create a shell let's say HelloShell.php in Console/Command

```
 <?php
    class HelloShell extends AppShell
    {
    public function main()
    {
    //Your functionality here...
    }

    }

    ?>
```

This shell can be called by Console/cake hello

2) Write the command `crontab-e` .This will open up the default editor or the editor which you select Now as we want that our shell should run after every 5 minutes write:-

```
*/5 * * * * /PATH TO APP/Console/cake hello
```

For better understanding refer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljgvo2jM234

3) If you want to call the action of the Controller in Shell simply import that particular controller let's say AppController by `App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');`

Now create the object AppController in Shell by

```
$object =new AppController();
$object->func_in_controller();
```

Now the parameters of function can be accessed in the Shell by `$object->func_param;`

Thanks!